# Unexpected output when finding variance of an image in OpenCV -Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, variance

My program finds the varaince values of an image at each window of a gridded image. The problem is when I print the values they don't match with what is shown in the ouput image. I have included an example image below.

Here is my code:

```
#import packages
import numpy as np
import cv2
import dateutil
import llist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import argparse

#Read in image as grey-scale
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg', 0)

#Set scale of grid 
scale = 6

#Get x and y components of image
y_len,x_len = img.shape

variance = []
for y in range(scale):
    for x in range(scale):
        #Crop image 9*9 windows
        cropped_img=img[(y*y_len)/scale:((y+1)*y_len)/scale,(x*x_len)/scale:((x+1)*x_len)/scale]

        (mean,stdv) = cv2.meanStdDev(cropped_img)
        var = stdv*stdv
        cropped_img[:] = var

        #Print mean_values array
        variance.append([var])
variance=np.asarray(variance)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=3)
print variance.reshape(1,scale,scale)

cv2.imshow('output_var',img)
#cv2.imwrite('images/output_var_300.jpg',img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the output image of the code above:
[image: Scale = 6]

From what I can tell the values below don't match the image above. Does anybody have any idea what is happening here?

```
print variance.reshape(1,scale,scale)
#[[[    17.208     43.201    215.305   1101.816   1591.606   2453.611]
#  [    46.664    121.162    326.59     809.223   1021.599   5330.989]
#  [    47.754     64.69     705.875   1625.177   3564.494  10148.449]
#  [    19.153    201.864    289.258    632.737   5285.449   4257.597]
#  [    37.621    159.51     271.725    282.291   2239.097    759.007]
#  [    26.108     98.456     32.958    505.609    575.916     70.741]]]
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :** Here is a more realistic output image for those who are interested:
[image: scale = 300]

Comment: What do you mean they don't match? As far as I can see, the `variance` matches the output image, the lower number means darker color, and the opposite, so the image is properly draw. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @Lawrence Ok so take the second row in the array as an example, "46.664" corresponds to the first block which is dark grey, "5330.989" corresponds to the last block which is light grey, so you would expect the lower the variance the draker the output, like you stated. But the penultimate block is "1021.599" which is a lower value than the last block but it is lighter. If you work through the array trying to match it to the image you will see it doesn't follow a pattern, the forth element in the array is where the pattern is broken.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. First thing that comes to my mind is normalization. Since color representation are 0-255 per channel, you might experiencing some behavior like overflow wrapping or similar. I would try to normalize the values and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take for example, the second row of `variance`. Since the color values are in range 0-255 per channel, we can try wrapping your values to fit into that range:

```
>>> row = [46.664, 121.162, 326.59, 809.223, 1021.599, 5330.989]
>>> wrapped = [x % 256 for x in row]
>>> wrapped
[46.66, 121.16, 70.58, 41.22, 253.59, 210.98]
```

And voila, it makes sense now.

Comment: Ok and how would I do this for an entire 2-d array like mine?

Comment: `var = [var % 256]` this was all I needed to do, placed after the line `cropped_img[:] = var`